# add functionality to an onClickListener in a derived class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, button, listener

I've read many threads on how to create and handle Button clicks using onClickListener. However, I couldn't find anything that solved this problem.

I have a class myActivity and I would like to create a second class myExtendedActivity which extends myActivity by adding some extra functionality. 
The class myActivity contains a lot of code which, for maintainability reasons, I don't want to duplicate. myExtendedActivity should behave exactly as myActivity with some extra function.

In particular in the onCreate method in myActivity I have the following code that add an onClickListener to my_button. The extended activity should just append a call to myExtraMethod.

```
myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button); 
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        [...]   //a lot of code here

        myExtraMethod();

    }
});
```

Note that myExtraMethod simply broadcasts an Intent and it is not affected by any other part of the code in the Listener.

What I would like to do is to extend the OnClickListener in myExtendedActivity so that it first executes exactly the code written for myActivity and than myExtraMethod defined in myExtendedActivity.

I don't want to modify myActivity which should be completely unaware if myExtendedActivity is included in the project or not.

Thank you very much

Comment: In your super class extract the code that is executed in the onClick Method in a separate method. After that you can use use super.yourMethod() in your subclass to call this method of the super class.

Answer (score 2):

Completely without modifying myActivity is barely possible.

You could use something like this in `MyActivity` (Some variant of the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)):

```
onCreate() {
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
           myMethod();
        }
    });

}

protected void myMethod() {
    [...]   //a lot of code here
}
```

And then in `MyExtendedActivty`:

```
@Override
protected void myMethod() {
    super.myMethod();
    myExtraMethod();
}
```

Comment: The solution of Alex DiCarlo using a distinct class for the Listener is also a  nice solution.

Comment: This is cleaner since you're playing with only 1 override, and it requires the least change. +1

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this can solve my problem. 

When I said I didn't want to modify myActivity, I just meant that I didn't want to include there any code that explicitly referred to myExtendedActivity. But I have no problem in moving all the code in the listener to a separate method and override it. Sorry for the misleading sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, the solution might be something like this:

In your layout for button you define the onClickListener from xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="handleButtonClick"
    />
```

Then, in MyActivity you implement method:

```
public void handleClick(View view) {

}
```

And in MyExtendedActivity you override it:

```
public class MyExtendedActivity extends MyActivity {
    @Override
    public void handleClick(View view) {
        super.handleClick(view);
        //your code goes here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying `myActivity`, you can't because you're instantiating an anonymous class, and the subclass has no way to "hook in" to that anonymous class.

If you can modify `myActivity`, then you could make the anonymous class from `myButton.setOnClickListener(...)` a static class, and in your subclass extend the listener class calling `super.onClick(v)`, followed by the functionality you expect.

Then add a method to get the correct listener

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(createMyButtonsListener())
```

that you can then override in the subclass providing the extended version.

Alternatively, add a method that can be overriden in a subclass (i.e. `myExtraMethod()`). that is called within your anonymous class.